# UnsafeMutablePointer<CFTypeRef> in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, core-foundation, unsafe-pointers, unsafemutablepointer

I'm attempting to call `SecItemCopyMatching` in my keychain utility class in order to get data out of the keychain, yet I'm running into a problem with getting the `result` argument, `UnsafeMutablePointer<CFTypeRef?>`.

The original statement (in Swift 2, before migrating to Swift 3) was

```
// query is a dictionary of [String : AnyObject]

var result: Data?
let status = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &result) {
    SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, UnsafeMutablePointer($0))
}
```

But in Swift 3, you are now required to call `.withMemoryRebound` in order to view memory. Based on what Xcode tells you to do, I tried this

```
var result: Data?
let status = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &result){
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: Data.self, capacity: 1){
        SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, UnsafePointer($0))
    }
}
```

Yet doing this, I get an error

> Cannot convert value of type '`UnsafePointer<_>`' to expected argument type '`UnsafeMutablePointer<CFTypeRef?>?`'

So, I tried using `CFTypeRef` instead of `Data`

```
var result: CFTypeRef?
let status = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &result){
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: CFTypeRef.self, capacity: 1){
        SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, UnsafePointer($0))
    }
}
```

Replacing `UnsafePointer($0)` with simply `$0` results in the same error message.

How can I get an `UnsafeMutablePointer<CFTypeRef?>` for getting data from keychain?

Comment: Please would you post how you're creating your query. I was previously doing just this and casting from a swift Dictionary to CFDictionary, but that no longer works for me in Swift 3. If I could see just a little more of the code I can apply this solution.

Comment: @TimSpears the problem with your code would probably be that the dictionary has to be a `[String : AnyObject]` - the auto-migrator (for me) changed this to `[String : Any]`. I updated [my answer to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39442056/2767207) to include the code I use

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your case, you do not need to use `withMemoryRebound` or `withUnsafeMutablePointer(to:)`.

Instead, you can just use

```
var result: AnyObject?
let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &result)

if status == noErr, let data = result as? Data {
    //use data...
}
```

Generally, when you need to pass an `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>` to a function, declare a variable of type `T` and pass it as an inout argument `&variable`. In your case, `T` is `CFTypeRef?`, and in Swift 3, `CFTypeRef` is just a typealias of `AnyObject`.

---

Even in Swift 2.2, you did not need to use `withUnsafeMutablePointer`

```
var result: AnyObject?  
let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query, &result)
```

Comment: Your solution is working for me. My result variable (defined using var, not let) is a SecKey, which is easily cast to CFTypeRef. Using just the ampersand results in the error `Cannot pass immutable value of type 'CFTypeRef?' as inout argument`

Answer (score 1):

The error message is somewhat misleading - the actual problem is that `result` has to be an `AnyObject?` - `withMemoryRebound` doesn't need to be used.

```
var result: AnyObject?
let status = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &result){
    SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, UnsafeMutablePointer($0))
}
```

Works as expected and gets the correct result from keychain - it just needs to be casted to `Data`. In fact, [`withUnsafeMutablePointer` doesn't even have to be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39448525/2767207).

So, my new code is

```
var query: [String : AnyObject] = [:]
//set up the query

var result: AnyObject?
let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &result)

var data: Data?
if status == noErr{
    data = result as? Data
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and the one by @OOPer, and neither seem to work for me, see my comment there. Any idea what's up?